# vba store recordset as integer variable

Tags: vba, excel, dao

First time poster, I finally had a question that I couldn't find an answer to here.

I have an MS Access query that returns 1 result (which is a number) that I want to store as an integer variable (x) so I can use it later for a loop. The issue is that because I'm using it as a recordset and the variable is an integer, I'm receiving a "Type Mismatch" error.

Right now I'm just storing the result to a cell and setting the variable equal to the cell:

```
Ws.Range("A1") = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").GetRows(1)

x = Ws.Range("A1")

Ws.Range("A1").Delete
```

And then later I just have a loop that runs *x* times:

```
For i = 0 To x
```

Basically, I just want to have some code that looks like this:

```
x = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").GetRows(1)
```

Any help here would be huge. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have anything to test this with, but is there a `.Value` property for the `.GetRows` method? Or what about `x = CInt(LBound(Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").GetRows(1)))`

Comment: When I add `.value` to end of the statement to make it: `x = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").GetRows(1).Value` I get an "Object Required" Error.

Comment: Wait, misread your statement. Your code doesn't error, but it returns x as a zero. But this is still progress.

Comment: `.GetRows(0, 0)` it's a 2-D array.    Also need to see your declaration for `x`

Comment: @Tim-Williams `.GetRows(0, 0)` returns the "Wrong number of arguments" error. The `.GetRows(1)` doesn't have any issues when I just ask it to be stored in the spreadsheet, so I _assume_ that's fine as is. I did declare x as an integer I just didn't display it in my question.

Comment: I changed the tags from `ADODB` to `DAO`. Still, `.Fields(0).Value` should work for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the correct result:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Recordset

db.MoveFirst
If IsNumeric(db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").Fields(0).Value) Then
    x = CInt(db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(Asset_Name) FROM Assets WHERE Active = True").Fields(0).Value)
Else
    MsgBox "The query did not return a number." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
End If
```

Note, that you are using `DAO` and not `ADO` as your original tags on the post indicated. Still, they both behave rather similar and the cursor is normally on the first row (when the data is returned). So, `MoveFirst` should not be necessary. Still, Microsoft themselves keep using it in its own sample code all the time. The first column if for `DAO` and `ADO` alike `.Fields(0)`.

Comment: PERFECT! Ran like a charm. Thank you, much appreciated, including the tag change